# Generate S3 presigned URL using lambda function for 7 days validity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

We have a lambda function with an execution role which has s3 access. Maximum session duration we kept with default option of 1 hour for the role.
When creating a s3 pre signed URL using this lambda function its observed that its valid for limited time only (less than 7 days). Sample code used from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

Error observed is expired token issue.
We want it to be valid for 7 days. Is it possible to create s3 presigned URL from lambda function with nodejs?

Comment: https://repost.aws/questions/QUd6IcnCLtQ6aN7Nd43TBUag/generate-s-3-presigned-url-with-7-day-expiry-via-lambda - only if you "hardcode" long lived IAM user credentials, which is generally a bad idea.

Comment: No we are not hardcoding long lived IAM user credentials. As mentioned earlier, we are using execution role.

Comment: That wasn't a question. The answer is: 'only if you "hardcode" long lived IAM user credentials, which is generally a bad idea'. Using a role this is not possible.

Comment: Can I ask... Why do you need pre-signed URLs with such long validity? Can you generate them closer to when the user would use the link?

Comment: We have some batch job running in aws, it stores result in s3 bucket. We want to share result of the same to stakeholders using s3 pre signed url. We want to give the link to users, not sure they will use immediatly but definitely within 7 days.

Answer (score 2):

A pre-signed URL is simply a 'normal' URL, with the addition of an **Access Key** and a **Signature**.

Amazon S3 will attempt to retrieve the object **using the permissions associated with the provided Access Key**. It verifies that the Signature matches both the request and the Secret Key associated with the Access Key.

This means that a pre-signed URL only **has the same permissions as the underlying Access Key**. If the Access Key only has a validity period of 1 hour, then the pre-signed URL will only work for 1 hour (since it is effectively using that Access Key).

To create a long-lived pre-signed URL, you will need to use equally long-lived credentials to *generate* the pre-signed URL.

By the way, it should be **quite rare to need a pre-signed URL that is valid for a long period**. A pre-signed URL should be generated as close as possible to when it will actually be used. For example, imagine a Dropbox-like service where a user is shown a list of files and they can click the filename to view the file. This page can be generated with pre-signed URLs as the links, each with a validity of perhaps 5-10 minutes. If the user refreshes the page, then new pre-signed URLs will be generated. There should be very little need to have pre-signed URLs valid for 7 days.